# Update row in SQLite without all information from the dataset

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I create some Objects based on information from my database. My table looks like this:

```
tbl_Book
+-----+-------+---------+-------+------+
| _id | Title | Author  | Pages | ISBN |
+-----+-------+---------+-------+------+
|   1 | Test1 | Author1 |   111 | 1234 |
|   2 | Test2 | Author2 |   222 | 2345 |
|   3 | Test3 | Author  |   333 | 3456 |
+-----+-------+---------+-------+------+
```

My created Objects only need the information from *id, title and the ISBN* so I only select these values from the database to create my Object. Now I want to update only the *ISBN* in the database so I have a method in my Object with this code:

```
Book b = new Book(id, title, isbn);
b.setISBN(value);

// Code from setISBN
public void setISBN(int isbn) 
{
    this.isbn= isbn;

    //  DB updaten
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put("_id", getId());
    cv.put("ISBN", isbn);

    db.replace("tbl_Book", null, cv);
}
```

But with this method it comes to a `SQLiteConstraintException` because *author, title and page* are null. How can I update a row in an table if I only have some information from the  dataset? All other items from the dataset should not be touched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using [Update()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)? It seems that the `_id` is your table's primary key. If your intention is just to update a record when you already have the primary key then it should be pretty simple:

```
String whereClause = "_id=" + getId();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("ISBN", isbn);

//update(String table,ContentValue value, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
db.update("tbl_Book", cv, whereClause, null);
```

As far as I know (*maybe I'm wrong*), [Replace()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#replace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) will first delete a row if it exists and then inserts a new record based on provided values. In your case I think, it deletes the corresponding record (*based on the id*) and then try to insert new one:

For instance let's say the `_id` is 1:

```
+-----+-------+---------+-------+------+
| _id | Title | Author  | Pages | ISBN |
+-----+-------+---------+-------+------+
|   1 | Test1 | Author1 |   111 | 1234 |
```

will be replaced by:

```
+-----+-------+---------+-------+------+
| _id | Title | Author  | Pages | ISBN |
+-----+-------+---------+-------+------+
|   1 | NULL  |   NULL  |  NULL | 4321 |
```

Which I don't think that fits your need. Therefore, I think for your purpose the `Update` suits better.

Comment: Of cause you are right. I have no idea why I used replace. Just thoughtless. And I think yout thoughts about the defintion from replace() are right. That makes sense. Great and extensively answer. Thank you!